# Standard C XCode Project from Scratch

Tags: c, xcode, gcc

I've programmed in Xcode using C (C99 by default) before, just by using the Command Line Tool template.
However, at school, I need to use `gcc-7` (I installed it via Homebrew and then `PATH`ed it) and standard C. Currently, I've been using Atom to edit my code, Terminal to build it (and we are required to use specific like switches `-Wall` and `-pedantic` when building it), and a lot of `printf` to debug it.

I'd like to do this all in Xcode (well, I'd like to stop `printf`-debugging and use Xcode's debugging features).

**How do I set up, starting from the Empty project template** (if you could call "empty" a template `:)`)**, an Xcode project using `gcc` (and wanted switches) and standard C?**

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to define a custom build rule.

Create a command line project, select the target and you'll see in the main window, a tab called "Build Rules". In the Build Rules view, look for "System C Compiler" and press the copy to target button. You can then edit the script to compile the code how you like.

Another way would be to create a new target using the "cross platform" tab and select "External Build System". This will allow you to use a script or `make` to build your project.

The third way (and my preferred way) is to ignore the instruction to use gcc and leave the compiler as clang. Clang is designed to be mostly command line compatible with gcc, so it is likely that the flags you are asked to use will be available with the same semantics.

In particular `-Wall` and `-pedantic` are definitely available to clang.In the build setting section, look for "other warning flags" and set `-Wall` there. You can set `-pedantic` with the "pedantic warnings" setting.